# Filters and handlers for FileUpload

Tags: gwt, file-upload, handler

In my GWT project I would like to:

1. Set a filter for the FileUpload widget so that it only accepts JPG files.
2. Enable `myButton` if the FileUpload widget, called `chooser`, has any file choosen. And disable `myButton` otherwise.

This is my code for point 2, but it does not work. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```
chooser.addAttachHandler(new Handler() {
public void onAttachOrDetach(AttachEvent event) {
if(chooser.isAttached()==false && myButton.isEnabled()==true)
    myButton.setEnabled(false);
else if(chooser.isAttached()==true && myButton.isEnabled()==false)
    myButton.setEnabled(true);
} });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Point 1: i think, is not possible to filter, which files can be choosed. The only one way for me is compare in the form handler, for example:

```
form.addFormHandler(new FormHandler(){
    public void onSubmit(FormSubmitEvent event){
      if(!extension.equals("pdf")) {
         // Error
      } else {
         // Submit
      }
    }
}
```

Another solution is to use ExtGWT with FileValidator:

```
fileUpload = new FileUploadField();
fileUpload.setWidth("240");
fileUpload.setValidator(new FileValidator());
fileUpload.setName("file");
fileUpload.setAccept("pdf");
```

@Point 2: the chooser.isAttached() is wrong condition imho....you need to check, if the input field is empty.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

@1, this is not a Form object, it is just a FileUpload object. Then which would be the right handler to set the filter?

@2, which handler should I use in order to know that the status of the FileUpload object has changed (file attached or dettached) and then perform the button action in that moment?

Comment: @1: yes, but the FileUpload must be added to a form, which will be submitet. And for the form you can use the addFormHandler @2: i have really no idea :) i would try something like chooser.getElement(0) (or 1 or 2 etc....until you get the input field). And after you get it, you can try something like inputField.getText() and compare it.

Answer (score 3):

I included a line like the one below:

```
fileUpload.getElement().setAttribute("accept", "image/png, image/gif,image/jpeg");
```

It did work for me using gwt FileUpload